# Optimize haskell function with huge numbers of power function call

Tags: performance, haskell

The following function is to find a number `n` which `1^3 + 2^3 + ... + (n-1) ^3 + n^3 = m`. Is there any chance this function can be optimized for speed?

```
findNb :: Integer -> Integer
findNb m = findNb' 1 0
  where findNb' n m' =
          if m' == m then n - 1
          else if  m' < m then findNb' (n + 1) (m' + n^3)
          else -1
```

I know there is a faster solution by using a math formula.

The reason I'm asking is that the similar implementation in JavaScript / C# seems far more faster than in Haskell. I'm just curious if it can be optimized.  Thanks.

### EDIT1: Add more evidences on the rum time

## Haskell Version:

With `main = print (findNb2 152000000000000000000000)`:

1. Compile with **-O2** and profiling: `ghc -o testo2.exe -O2 -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts pileofcube.hs`. Here is total time from profiling report:

   total time  =        **0.19** secs (190 milliseconds)   (190 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
2. Compile with -O2 but no profiling: `ghc -o testo22.exe -O2 pileofcube.hs`. Run it with `Measure-Command {./testo22.exe}` in powershell. The result is:

   Milliseconds      : **157**

### JavaScript Version:

Code:

```
function findNb(m) {
    let n = 0;
    let sum = 0;
    while (sum < m) {
      n++;
      sum += Math.pow(n, 3);
    }

    return sum === m ? n : -1;
}
var d1 = new Date();
findNb(152000000000000000000000);
console.log(new Date() - d1);
```

Result: **45** milliseconds running in Chrome on the same machine

### EDIT2: Add C# Version

As @Berji and @Bakuriu commented, comparing to the JavaScript version above is not fair as it uses double-precision floating point numbers underlying and could not give the correct answer even.  So I implemented it in C#, here is the code and result:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BigInteger m = BigInteger.Parse("152000000000000000000000");
            var s = new Stopwatch();
            s.Start();
            long n = 0;
            BigInteger sum = 0;
            while (sum < m)
            {
                n++;
                sum += BigInteger.Pow(n, 3);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sum == m ? n : -1);
            s.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Escaped Time: {s.ElapsedMilliseconds} milliseconds.");
        }
```

Result: Escaped Time: **457** milliseconds.

### Conclusion

Haskell version is faster than C# one...

I was wrong at start because I didn't realized JavaScript use double-precision floating point numbers under the hood due to my poor JavaScript knowledge.

At this point seems the question does not make sense anymore...

Comment: Have you compiled your program, can you give some evidence of your claim? Usually you use `seq` or bang patterns to make calculations more strict. Also switching to Into or Word64 provides a significant speedup

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Added more details. I don't think Word64 works as the input may out of range.

Comment: Notice that in JavaScript all number are double-precision floating point numbers. Your `m` is already out of the range where integers are precisely representable; this code neither will give accurate results nor is it comparable to Haskell's `Integer`s.

Comment: The equivalent Haskell code has type `Double -> Double` and uses `** 3` instead of `^3`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, wouldn't `^3` be faster than `**3`?

Comment: @dfeuer I don't think so. `^` is a more generic operation while `**` is specifically floating exponentiation which is what the javascript code does.

Answer (score 6):

Haskell too can use `Double` to get the wrong answer in less time:

```
% time ./so
./so  0.03s user 0.00s system 95% cpu 0.038 total
```

And Javascript too can get the correct result via npm-installing `big-integer` and using bigInt everywhere instead of Double:

```
% node so.js
^C
node so.js  35.62s user 0.30s system 93% cpu 38.259 total
```

... or maybe it isn't as trivial as that.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT : I realized afterward that's not what the author of the question wanted. I'll keep it there as a in case someone wants to know the formula in question, but otherwise please disregard.

---

There is indeed a formula that lets you compute this in constant time (rather than n iterations). Since I couldn't remember the exact formula from school, I did a bit of searching, and here is is: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Cubes.

In haskell code, that would translate to

```
findNb n = n ^ 2 * (n + 1) ^ 2 / 4
```

which I believe should be much faster.

Comment: Yes, but his point was he didn't want to change the algorithm, he wanted to use the naive approach as a benchmark and figure out the performance issues with the language and compiler under question.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I misread the question (that'll teach be to not do this before breakfast). Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this wording of that algorithm is faster, but try this?

```
findNb :: Integer -> Integer
findNb m = length $ takeWhile (<=m) $ scanl1 (+) [n^3 | n <- [1..]]
```

(This has different semantics in the undefined case, though.)